# RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver inside map or for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

ERROR: `RDD`transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, `rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x)` is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the `rdd1.map` transformation. For more information, see `SPARK-5063`.

```
val omnitureStitchedEntriesWithExposures: List[OmnitureFeedOutputEntry] = listEntries.map(entry => {
    val guid = entry.getProp12()
    val uisObjectListForGuid: Seq[MappedExposureEntry] = uisExposures.lookup(guid)
    uisObjectListForGuid match {
      case Nil =>
        logInfo("task=uis_omniture_guid_match, guid=" + guid + " visitorid=" + entry.getXVisitorId())
        entry
      case _ => OmnitureFeedOutputEntry.cloneWithExposures(entry, uisObjectListForGuid)
    }
  })
```

Comment: So? What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually don't be confused driver does't execute these statement it will only add all these transformations into the DAG and whenever you will call action it will execute whole DAG on cluster or we can say worker nodes. Second point yes you can't use RDD transformations and actions inside transformation and actions because that closure will run on worker nodes and the RDD's are not serializable.